# About Creating a Vertex on the Edge

Tags: modeling, vertices

I am modelling a cushion. As in the picture, I connected vertexes on beveled edges but I want to extend them to the outer edges too. How can I create a vertex on the outer edge to connect it to the existing one?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Press K to enter knife mode, click on the first vertex, then click on the edge where you want your new vertex. Hit space when you are done, Voila!